# Sharepoint Update automated

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have no experience in SharePoint development. I work on a BI Product and it generates reports from a SharePoint site. Some of the columns in this SharePoint site are:

```
State   Status  Technical   Legislation
```

When the columns - Status, Technical and Legislation are updated, I need to automatically update another SharePoint site. This site is not yet available, but it should have the following columns:

```
State   Alert Reason          Current Status    Previous Status        Status Last Updated  Technical Last Updated  Legislation Last Updated
Alabama Status Modified       Active State      Currently Implementing  8/13/2013        
        Legislation Updated                                                                                            8/7/2013
        Technical Updated                                                                       8/12/2013
```

If the Status, legislation or Technical is updated again for Alabama, then only the latest update should reflect in the new sharepoint site. Is this possible? How can it be done?
Regards,
Jude

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use custom code for this and develop an **Event Receiver** in Visual Studio.  Event receivers are attached to lists (or libraries or sites) and fire when an event occurs.  In your case it sounds like you would need to implement the **ItemUpdated** event and then run some custom process at that point.

Here is a good tutorial on this:
[Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010%28v=office.14%29.aspx)